# Unable to install Xvfb on Suse Linux

Tags: python, selenium, suse, xvfb, pyvirtualdisplay

I am trying to run the selenium-webdriver using the python library on Suse 11.4 (64-bit)
For it to run headlessly, it requires another python package "pyvirtualdisplay" to run. I have been able to install both perfectly.
The problem now is that pyvirtualdisplay requires a system level package called Xvfb which is not installed.
Zypper is unavailable and i need to install this using a tarball or an rpm.
Please guide me as to how i can install this library and where i can find it. I have been unable to find a suitable Xvfb package that I can install on this distribution of Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11364/installing-xvfb-on-suse) post Xvfb is provided by the `xorg-x11-server` package. Since you dont have access to zypper you can download that package directly from [here](https://software.opensuse.org/package/xorg-x11-server) ([direct link to 64 bit RPM for Suse 11.4](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:/11.4/standard/x86_64/xorg-x11-server-7.6_1.9.3-15.18.4.x86_64.rpm)) and install it manually.